# dynamic sql in a pipeline function oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle18c

```
create or replace function fn_master(col_name VARCHAR2) return master_file pipelined
Is
       TYPE MYMASTER_FILE IS RECORD (
        id                         NUMBER(5),
        name                        VARCHAR2(101),
        school                      varchar2(2000)
       
   );



 
   TYPE MASTER_FILE_ARRAY IS TABLE OF MYMASTER_FILE
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
 
   l_info MASTER_FILE_ARRAY;
    
begin 



execute immediate 'select id, name, school from x_table where ' || col_name || '= ''xxxxxx'' ' 

   BULK COLLECT INTO l_info;
 
   FOR i IN 1 .. l_info.COUNT
   LOOP
                              PIPE row(master_file(               
                                    l_info(i).id,
                                    l_info(i).name ,
                                    l_info(i).school
                                  
                                ));
   END LOOP;
end fn_master;
```

here is function that I have created to accept a column from this table and print the rows returned. I have made it simplistic for the purpose of presenting it here on stack overflow.

when i try to compile i am getting the error

```
PLS-00630: pipelined functions must have a supported collection return type
```

however when i added a return clause it tells me

```
PLS-00633: RETURN statement in a pipelined function cannot contain an expression
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
PLS-00630: pipelined functions must have a supported collection return type
```

can you all help me to solve this

Comment: is the way i approached the function, the right way?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code, relating more to return types than the use of dynamic SQL.

Firstly, the return type of a pipelined function should be a table type, not a row type.  You've set it to `master_file`. (Incidentally, you haven't actually defined this type anywhere, but let's not dwell on this.  Maybe you meant `mymaster_file`?)

However, if you were then to set it to `master_file_array`, you would then get the error `PLS-00498: illegal use of a type before its declaration`.  In a way this makes sense: Oracle doesn't know what type this function returns without compiling the function, but it needs to know the return type before it can compile th function.

So instead, let's define an object type and a nested-table type, so we can use that as the return type:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MASTER_FILE AS OBJECT (
        id                         NUMBER(5),
        name                       VARCHAR2(101),
        school                     varchar2(2000)
);
/

CREATE TYPE MASTER_FILE_ARRAY AS TABLE OF MASTER_FILE;
/
```

I then attempted to use these types with the `BULK COLLECT INTO` clause of your  `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement, thinking that the types you had declared inside your function weren't necessary any more.  However, when I did this, I got the wonderfully-helpful error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -`.  It seems you can only use PL/SQL associative arrays (i.e. collections declared with the `INDEX BY` clause) with `BULK COLLECT INTO`, so let's try again using the collection type you defined inside your function:

```sql
create or replace function fn_master(col_name VARCHAR2) return master_file_array pipelined
is
  TYPE MYMASTER_FILE IS RECORD (
    id        NUMBER(5),
    name      VARCHAR2(101),
    school    varchar2(2000)
  );
 
  TYPE MYMASTER_FILE_ARRAY IS TABLE OF MYMASTER_FILE
    INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
 
  l_info MYMASTER_FILE_ARRAY;

begin 

  execute immediate 'select id, name, school from x_table where ' || col_name || '= ''xxxxxx'' ' BULK COLLECT INTO l_info;
 
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_info.COUNT
  LOOP
    PIPE row(master_file(               
        l_info(i).id,
        l_info(i).name ,
        l_info(i).school
    ));
  END LOOP;
end fn_master;
/
```

Note that I've used the prefix `MY` for the names of the types declared inside the function.  The name of the PL/SQL associative array type inside your function is now `MYMASTER_FILE_ARRAY`, and `l_info` is declared to be of this type.  The names of types declared outside the function do not have this prefix, so the function returns `MASTER_FILE_ARRAY` and calls to `PIPE ROW(...)` use `MASTER_FILE`.

I created a table `x_table` and inserted some data into it, and after making the modifications above I was able to call your function and get it to return some data from this table.

Answer (score 2):

The point of a pipelined function is to be able to stream a set of results back to the caller without the need to instantiate the entire set as a collection in memory. This means you can start returning rows as soon as the first row is available, without waiting for the last row or allocating memory for the complete set. The function as posted fetches all the rows into an array before piping anything, so there does not seem any point in making it pipelined in the first place.

A truly pipelined implementation might look something like this:

```
create or replace function fn_master
    ( col_name varchar2 )
    return master_file_array
    pipelined
as
    c_results sys_refcursor;
    r master_file := master_file(null, null, null);
begin
    open c_results for 'select id, name, school from demo where ' || col_name || '= ''ABC'' ';

    loop
        fetch c_results into r.id, r.name, r.school;
        exit when c_results%notfound;
        pipe row(r);
    end loop;
end fn_master;
```

By the way, I recommend putting some care into code layout, as it makes the code easier to understand, debug, and maintain.